# Does .find() traverse the DOM again if the selector is cached?

Tags: jquery, caching

I use this simple function to cache my selectors:

```
var selector_cache = function(){
    var collection = {};
    function get_from_cache( selector ) {
        if (undefined === collection[selector]) {
            collection[selector] = $(selector);
        }
        return collection[selector];
    }
    return { get: get_from_cache };
};
```

To get my cached selectors I do the following:

```
window.selectors = new selector_cache();
var $selectors = window.selectors;
var $program_home = $selectors.get('section#program_home');
```

My question is: Doing `$program_home.find('.home_section');` jQuery is going to traverse the DOM again? Or does it get the children of the selector from the cached version?

I would like to avoid to traverse the DOM again, so if jQuery traverses the DOM again, maybe the best solution is to cache the children as well (?) like this: `$selectors.get('section#program_home .home_section');`

Thanks for any suggestion!

Comment: The pattern you've created here seems like a big headache for very little gain.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan not really. My app uses phonegap with JQM. JQM is really slow and I need to cache every single selector and to manage them the right way in order to speed up the app

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "Doing $program_home.find('.home_section'); jQuery is going to
>   traverse the DOM again? Or does it get the children of the selector
>   from the cached version?"

Well, neither.

The `$program_home` variable contains a jQuery object that contains references to the elements that were found earlier using the `section#program_home` selector.

The `find` method won't search the entire DOM, it will only search inside those elements. If there are currently other elements that would also match the original selector, those are not included.

The selector cache is not involved at all in this operation.

Answer (score 1):

Your `$selectors` variable is a jQuery object, and you've explicitly invoked a method on that object (`.find`) so yes, it will traverse the DOM again (albeit only looking at descendants of that node, not the entire DOM).

Comment: Mh...So is that the same for .attr() ? I mean, whatever method I invoke, jQuery will traverse the DOM again?

Comment: the only computation you save is querying the DOM for the very thing you have cached

Comment: @A. Wolff: Good example (interesting side-effect). Thanks.

Comment: @A.Wolff that doesn't show anything. If you call `remove()` an element is just detached from the `DOM` and will live fine as a detached fragment.

Comment: @David Fregoli: But note the selector in the output = `"div span"` :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie its children live as detached fragments as well

Comment: @David Fregoli: Any other definitive test you can think of to see if the first part of the DOM is hit again? I am scratching my head to think of one at the moment.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie this is the exact same thing, jQuery objects can live outside the DOM fine and well http://jsfiddle.net/w7Lyt4by/1/

Comment: @DavidFregoli That's ok but we are talking about traversing the DOM or not. Any call on referenced node detached from DOM means that we don't traverse the DOM. Did i misunderstand it?

Comment: @A.Wolff IMHO, it makes no difference whether the node is currently a descendent of the `document` or not - it's still "DOM".  It's implicit in `.find` that it'll only consider descendants of the given selector and not start from the `document` node every time.

Comment: @Alnitak the difference would be in term of performance, this is how i assume the whole question.